# Unrecognised arguments trying to submit a pyspark job on DataProc

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, data-processing

I'm trying to submit a pyspark job on a dataproc cluster by running the following command (via Powershell):

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark gs://path-to-file/myfile.py `
  --region europe-west2 `
  --cluster my-dataproc-cluster `
  -- 20230101 gs://path-to-put-output
```

The 2 job args are a date and a destination bucket.

The job fails immediately with

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pyspark) unrecognized arguments:
  20230101
  gs://path-to-put-output
  To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
```

I have tried a few combinations of adding extra dashes before the args, adding the arg names in the script etc, but it always ends with the same error.

Can someone help show me what obvious little thing I am missing?

Also - just to prove that the python script is set up to handle the args, here is the entrypoint:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    DATE = sys.argv[1]
    PATH = sys.argv[2]
    MyClass(DATE, PATH).compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution - needs a second set of double dashes:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark gs://path-to-file/myfile.py `
  --region europe-west2 `
  --cluster my-dataproc-cluster `
  -- -- 20230101 gs://path-to-put-output
```